# Unable to deploy pipeline to AWS CI/CD account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, cicd, aws-devops

I am trying to deploy pipeline to `CI/CD` account. However I'm getting below error.

```
npm run cdk deploy LandingPagePipelineStack -- --profile cicd


> landingpage@0.3.13 cdk
> cdk deploy LandingPagePipelineStack --profile cicd

 Failed to get credentials for "cicd" profile. Make sure to run "aws configure sso --profile cicd && aws sso login --profile cicd"
```

I have also tried to logged in using below command and it was successful.

```
aws configure sso --profile cicd && aws sso login --profile cicd
```

I'm following step number 5 at [AWS tutorial](https://catalog.us-east-1.prod.workshops.aws/workshops/13304db2-f715-48bf-ada0-92e5c4eea945/en-US/040-cicd/23-deploy-pipeline).

Please help me to deploy pipeline to `CI/CD` account.

Comment: Please make sure that you followed the first three pages of this tutorial to the last letter. Also, what happens when you use `aws s3 ls --profile cicd` command?

Answer (score 0):

After you execute the command in the output (`aws configure sso --profile cicd && aws sso login --profile cicd`) you should be able to simply execute `npm run cdk deploy LandingPagePipelineStack -- --profile cicd`

Make sure that any time you want to execute cdk with sso context, that you have active temp credentials, by executing `sso login`